# SSRS Where can I place sub reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, subreports

This is not the greatest question, but I have goggled and hunted and pecked for several days and have not found the solution. Where within a SSRS report can a sub-report be placed? Are there any locations that it might seam invisible or be hard to find?

I have created simple sub reports, and can find many tutorials out there for that. This is my problem. I have to update and migrate an old report and its sub reports. I can only find reference to one sub report within the main report or its sub report. The first three pages of the report and the sub report I know of display fine. However on the last two pages of the report there are "Error: Sub report could not be shown." messages displayed.

I have not been able to find any reference to other sub reports. Where else could a reference to a sub report be placed?

The image below has selected a section where I found the reference to the sub report I was able to find. The rest of the areas appear as a "Rectangle" when I right click and I can find no reference to other sup reports in them.

[image: The selected section is where I found the reference to the sub report I was able to find.]

Comment: Are you trying to track down references to the subreport within an existing .rdl? If so, the .rdl file is a pretty clean XML file. You can open it up and search through the text for your subreport's name.

Comment: I've only been using the graphical interface, so this guidance might be the trick I needed. I will be looking into it.

Comment: This does indeed let me track down the other sub report names that need to be updated and migrated. Thanks Jaime. Feel free to put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.rdl files are actually XML files generated by the designer. And they usually have a pretty clean structure as well.

You can open these files in a text editor or by right clicking on the file in Visual Studio and selecting "View Code"

There you can use the usual text tools to look for item names. The `Names` of items can help you figure out what items in the XML map to what in the GUI: when you are back in the designer, you can use the drop down at the top of the properties window to select an item by name and it will be highlighted in the designer window.